# RESTful API security

Tags: api, security, rest, authentication

I would like to develop RESTful API for my web application. Client have to be clear JS + HTML and user have to somehow authenticate in system. I've read few articles about security and RESTful API but some point still are not clear for me. As I've understood at the first step user have to provide his credentials to server. After that server have to validate user credentials and if they are valid, sent some encoded token to user (assume it will be [user key]:[user IP]:[token creation time]). After user authentication client have to sent this this key with each API call. That's how I've understood RESTful API authentication principes.

With such solution I assume that token can be stolen and another user can access to secured user data (even if IP is included to access token and there will be validation on each request). For this purpose I plan to include token creation time but as I understand with such solution I have to renew access token each time when it expiring - in this case it's not clear for me how to implement "remember me" functionality.

It's not clear for me how to implement 100% safe authentication for my RESTful API. Maybe I'm missing something. Or maybe my understanding of authentication principes is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends from what authentication scenario you are using. For example when dealing with in ASP.NET MVC + REST with Basic Authentication it will produce for you token which is in the fact Base64 encoded string '{username}:{password}'. And you are right it could be stolen, that's why for Basic Auth HTTPS is must, as token goes throw Authentication header with Basic schema.

For REST security most suitable and secure are OpenId and OAuth. Just don't reinvent wheel and use already existing standards. OAuth in compare to OpenID includes not only authentication but authorization as well. OAuth already describes all nuances with token renew and token creation time and so on.

Now practical how to implement OAuth in REST. First of all read standard. For your case read with attention [Implicit Grant flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2), because standard has multiple flows for different client with different trust level and security.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

And after that you can try some already implemented library in technological stack you are using either Java or .NET. For client it is not so important to use library in compare  but for server implementation

About potential security problem read here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.

[Some think that OAuth 2.0 is less secure that OAuth 1.0](http://hueniverse.com/2010/09/oauth-bearer-tokens-are-a-terrible-idea/), and it is also dependant from token format. Anyway access token should be passed in HTTP Header and through HTTPS as well as clientid should be stored and passed securely.